# Ember build issue: "Cannot use the decorators and decorators-legacy plugin together"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, babeljs, bitbucket-pipelines, broccolijs

I have recently encountered an issue with building my ember project with bitbucket pipelines:

```
+ ember build --environment="production"
Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Building
Environment: production
cleaning up
cleaning up...
Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel: ember-data]) in ember-data/adapters/json-api.js
Cannot use the decorators and decorators-legacy plugin together
```

I am currently using ember-cli version 3.8.1.

The issue occurs with all build environments, not just production.
What baffles me is that no new npm package or ember addon was added between last successful build and the ones that have been failing since - and now if I re-run the successful build, that will also fail.

I have gone back in the commit history to a commit that worked, then fast-forward into the present step-by-step - always deleting the node_modules and reinstalling the packages. It always works locally, but it will always fail when the pipeline is run.

I have also tried updating my docker image.

I have already gone through and tried the solutions listed [here](https://github.com/ember-decorators/ember-decorators/issues/90) - but it seems like they have already been addressed in version 3.8.1.

Also, if it is any help, this is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
         name: Building Ember Project
         script:
          - npm install
          - npm install firebase-tools
          - ember build --environment="production"
      - step:
         trigger: manual
         deployment: production
         name: Deploy to Production
         script:
          - firebase use prod
          - firebase deploy --non-interactive --token ${FIREBASE_TOKEN}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What version of ember-cli-babel do you have?

Comment: Also, have you cleared your npm cache?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Thank you for the answer! The version of my ember-cli-babel is 7.1.2 and I had cleared the cache in one of my many attempts to replicate the issue locally, but I was not successful.

Comment: can you upgrade your ember-cli-babel to latest? does that change anything?

Comment: The issue seems to be gone as of yesterday. No upgrades done, nothing changed. It's a mystery :/ I only hope this doesn't happen again as I don't even know how it got caused or went away in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a sub-dependency changing on the fly under the hood. Do you have an npm or yarn lockfile commited as part of your repo? Lockfiles are specifically designed to keep from hitting snags like this

Comment: Yes, the package.lock is always included, hence my bewilderment at this issue :/

Comment: @lorsini although the package lock file may be there, is the NPM version that runs in CI for you one that supports the lock file? It's possible that it doesn't which would explain your symptoms ...

Comment: Oh I see... oddly enough, as I pushed into the repository - like, 5 minutes ago - the build was successful and the deployment went without a hiccup. Just last night, it failed. No updates done, nothing major changed with the exception of some other packages added. Super weird....

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the below errors,

`Build error : “Cannot use the decorators and decorators-legacy plugin together”`

`Build error:  'relationshipStateFor' is not exported by  -private\system\record-data-for.js`

On browser got `Expected store.createRecordDataFor to be implemented but it wasn't.`

Reason for the above error is with ember-data addon and mismatch in ember-cli version installed for my project.

In your `package.json`, You might have defined ember-cli version( `"ember-cli": "^3.11.0",`) with `^` symbol this means it will install latest version which is less than the 4.0.0. So your ember-cli in node_modules might be installed to the latest version.

The above mentioned error is caused by the ember-cli version which was installed and pointed to 3.15.0. So I have removed the `^` and updated `"ember-cli": "3.11.0",` and removed node_modules and did `npm install` that solves the above problem.